# Integrating differential form on the boundary of k singular cube

Tags: differential-forms

While reading Spivak's CoM, I was wondering how we verify
$$
\int_{\partial c}\omega=\int_{\partial I^k} c^* \omega 
$$
for a arbitrary $k$ singular cube $c$, where $w$ is a $k-1$ form. This is used in proving the Euclidean space version of Stokes theorem.

This should be easy but I don't seem to get it right. I tried to decompose the boundary into chain of $k-1$ cubes. Let $\partial c=\sum a_ic_i$. Then
$$
\int_{\partial c}\omega=\sum a_i \int_{c_i}\omega =\sum a_i \int _{I^{k-1}_i} c_i^*\omega \overset{?}{=}\int_{\partial I^k} c^* \omega 
$$
But now there seems to be pull back via different faces of the cube, and I still can't see how to proceed throught that.

Edit: I’m guessing that we can formally sum the $c^*_i$’s but I’m not sure if that’s right.

Edit 2: Can I argue that by definition $c^*_i \omega=(c\circ I^{k-1}_{i})^*\omega=\omega\circ (c\circ I^{k-1}_{i})_*=\omega\circ c_*$?

Comment: Although I'm not fond of it, you should probably use Spivak's notation for the boundary on p. 98 — namely $c_{(i,\alpha)}$ — encoding the restrictions of the singular cube to the boundary faces.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your reply! But I guess that’s a purely notational issue? I think my issue before is trying to make sense of the formal sum of differential form pulled back via different faces of the singular cube. After thinking it for some time, it makes more sense to me now.

Comment: That's the whole point of a singular chain in the first place, whether you're talking about boundaries or not.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. I think Spivak’s chain is just a formal sum of singular cubes? I wonder if he ever explicitly mentioned how to pull back a chain because I didn’t quite see such an example in the book. I may be missing something

Comment: Yes, middle of p. 101.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! I did invoke that definition in the body of my question..I think I was just conceptually confused for a while why the last equality in that equation I wrote above is true. Now I see that it should follow from the definition, just like the first equality in the equation. I hope this is correct.